# Incorrect syntax while accessing SQL table using Python

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to access a SQL Express database using Python, but I keep getting an incorrect syntax error. I've tried a few variations based of other examples I've seen, but nothing's working.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_connection='yes',
                      driver='{SQL Server}',
                      server='VACE1\RCARCHIVE',
                      database='TestDB')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from 100000MTL1")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

The error is

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '100000'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I've tried changing the database and the name of the database, but I'm not sure if that is where the error is exactly, so I'm totally stuck now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape your table name like this

```
select * from [100000MTL1]
```

since table names usually don't start with numbers.

Comment: I... totally missed that, it works now thank you so much!

Comment: Basically, any identifier not confirming to rules have to be delimited. You can also use " (double quotes) in place of square brackets. Read more on SQL Server database identifier rules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15